# Is using hibernate type property names when using spring boot a good approach

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

In my current codebase, I have a RestController, and I am using hibernate with it. As of now, I am using the same hibernate configuration which one would usually use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg">
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Also, in my pom.xml, I have added:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.28</version>
        </dependency>
```

But to get this working I had to add the attribute `exclude` like this :
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
Otherwise, it was throwing some error. Another issue I noticed was even though 
hbm2ddl.auto is set to true, which would have created the tables in a simple hibernate application. But it's not happening now. It throws an error if the table is not there but seems to be 
 working fine if it's there.
I changed the MySQL dialect in the hibernate.cfg.xml to :

org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect

And now it's automatically creating the table. That's weird when I was using the same hibernate code without spring boot the earlier Dialect was working
This is the main code that starts the application:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
public class SpringServerMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(SpringServerMain.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show me your code where `SpringBootApplication` annotation is?

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej Added the code and also the table creation is happening fine when I changed to `MySQL8Dialect`

Comment: Spring boot have own `application.properties` file for configuration

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej But hibernate properties are generally specified in hibernate.cfg.xml
Isn't it better to specify them separately

Comment: if you are using spirng boot then all configuration are inserted in `application.properties`

Comment: If using spring keep it in property file it's a convention , honestly if I was looking this project i will spend half an hour to figure out where the configuration is ,if it's not in either config package or properties .